# Rails 5 - jQuery validate on form.select only works after submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have a drop-down that I need to validate, but it is not behaving like I expect it to.

```
# app/views/forms/_form.html.erb

<%= form.select :environment, [ 'Production', 'Staging', 'Test' ],
{ prompt: 'Select an Environment' }, { required: true } %>


# app/assets/javascripts/forms.js
$('form#new_form').validate({
  validClass: "valid",
  errorClass: "invalid",
    rules: {
      'form[environment]': { required: true },
    }
});
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Click on the drop-down
2. Select an option; Production, Staging, or Test
3. The `valid` class gets added to the drop-down
4. -- This is where the issue occurs -- Click **back** on the drop-down list and select the prompt **Select an Environment**.
5. The `invalid` class does **not** get added to the drop-down.

The above steps **only work as expected** when I submit the form and watch it error out. Then, when I repeat steps 1-5, the `valid` class gets added when I select an option (Production, Staging, or Test), and the `invalid` class gets added when I select the prompt **Select an Environment**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs (https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) it behaves like expected.

> Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before
>   submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through
>   fields without getting annoying messages – they won't get bugged
>   before having the chance to actually enter a correct value
>
> Once a field is marked invalid, it is eagerly validated: As soon as
>   the user has entered the necessary value, the error message is removed

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I thought I was going nuts! I understand from a user perspective that we don't really want to 'annoy' them with so many messages, but is it feasible to make this behavior 'un-lazy'?